# missing user cookie(to validate session user) facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I've implemented facebook SDK for android in mycode. I've save user token facebook in server. and use it to invite request to facebook friend. but it show error

API Error code : 110
API Error Descriptions : Invalid user ID
Error Message : Missing user cookie (to validate session user)

and this is my code to send request

```
Session msession;
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("to", id_friend);
params.putString("message", "Invite your friend");

msession = Session.getActiveSession();

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
Date convertedDate = new Date();
try {
     convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(fb_token_expired);
} catch (ParseException e) {

     e.printStackTrace();
}
    final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("read_requests", "read_mailbox", "manage_notifications");

AccessToken token=AccessToken.createFromExistingAccessToken(fb_token_user, convertedDate, null,AccessTokenSource.CLIENT_TOKEN, PERMISSIONS);

 msession = Session.openActiveSessionWithAccessToken(c, token, new StatusCallback(){
 @Override
 public void call(Session aSession, SessionState aState, Exception aException) {
            if (aException != null) {

            }


        }
   });

if(msession.isOpened()){
        requestsDialog = (new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(this,msession,params))
                  .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                            FacebookException error) {
                            if (error != null) {
                                if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {

                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Request cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                        "Network Error", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            } else {
                                final String requestId = values.getString("request");
                                if (requestId != null) {


                                    Log.e("success", "success");


                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Request cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }   
                        }



                    })
                    .build();
            requestsDialog.show();
        }
```

any solution?? thanks :)

Comment: Why are you using this mechanism to create a session? Where are you getting the access tokens from? You should not have to mess with access tokens directly using the SDK.

Comment: before that , of course I get access token from facebook sdk , but in this situation , I wanna save that access token in server , and create session from existing access token